# How can I only pull 5 tweets from this array?

Tags: php, mysql, api, twitter

How can I only pull an exact number of tweets such as 5? I have tried to use the count function but it's not working? Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you :)

```
$stwt = array('HarbourBridge','SyndeyBridge','bridgeclimb');


for($n = 0; $n < count($stwt); $n++){
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = "?q=#'$stwt[$n]'&result_type=recent";
$requestMethod = 'GET';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$data=$twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
              ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
              ->performRequest();
$phpdata = json_decode($data, true);
 //Loop through the status updates and print out the text of each
foreach ($phpdata["statuses"] as $status) {
    echo("<p>" . $status["text"] . "</p>");
    stwitter1 = (string)$status["text"];
    $stwt = "SELECT * FROM STweets ";
    mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO STwitter(STweets) 
                          VALUES ('$stwitter1')");

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Where you want to limit at 5 tweets ? from the api or your sql query ?

Comment: This code should also be protected against `cross site scripting` and `SQL injection`.. Don't blindly trust the api from twitter to contain safe data..

Comment: From the api I would want to limit to 5

Comment: Check out [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) you should be able to use it after the `json_encode()`

Comment: Okay will do thank you